# Trigger for yaml release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I need to know if it is possible to trigger a yaml release pipeline from a Classic Release pipeline.(the one created from the Releases tab under pipelines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **Yes**. You can use the [Trigger Build Task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) extension and queue the YAML pipeline from the release:

[image]

Or use [Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline) extension.

[image]